# What languages support covariance on inherited methods' return types?

Tags: c#, java, oop, programming-languages, covariance

I originally asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46933/why-doesnt-inheritance-work-the-way-i-think-it-should-work), but in finding an answer, discovered that my original problem was a lack of support in C# for covariance on inherited methods' return types. After discovering that, I became curious as to what languages *do* support this feature.

I will accept the answer of whoever can name the most.

**EDIT**: John Millikin correctly pointed out that lots of dynamic languages support this. To clarify:

**I am only looking for static/strongly typed languages.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- C++
- Java
- REALbasic
- Eiffel
- Sather
- Modula-3

Answer (score 2):

Any dynamic languages, of course -- Python, Ruby, Smalltalk, Javascript, etc.

Comment: I see that you removed Java from the list because "Java only allows it for objects in the same inheritance hierarchy" but I think thats what I'm asking for..or is it?

Answer (score 0):

> Basically what I'm asking is what languages support what I'm trying to do here.

Does C# let you specify different data types for the `get()` and `set()` methods? If not, I would split them into actual `Leg get_leg()` and `set_leg(DogLeg)` functions. Otherwise one of two things will happen: 1) overspecification of `get_leg()` 2) underspecification of `set_leg()`.

Answer (score 0):

C++ supports covariant return types.

Answer (score 0):

Java added support for this in 1.5.  It will not compile in earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Ivan Hamilton and Mat Noguchi, C++ supports the feature. But note that covariant return types are broken for template classes which inherit from some base in MSVC 7.X through 9.X (and probably 6 also). You get error C2555.

Answer (score -1):

> but I think thats what I'm asking for..or is it?

I frankly don't know what you're asking. Java apparently has the same support for return-type covariance as C#, so if whatever you're looking for is lacking in C#, it's lacking in Java also.